# Issues with HTTPS and landing pages?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, https, ruby-on-rails

We are going to setup HTTPS for a rails app but I was wondering if there would be any issues with the landing page if it were on HTTPS as well?

Ideally, we would like to have the landing page on HTTP, but once a client logs into the app, it should direct to HTTPS.  Can anyone explain or link a how to setup this up (I've already purchased an SSL)?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the urls in links, images, buttons, in your web pages are either relative or dynamically match the http https of the page, there shouldn't be any issues.

If any links/urls on your pages specifically call for http://, then users might receive the "do you want to view only the secure content on this page?" message along with other annoyances.

Also note that large data such as images take longer to load.